# How to plot a 3D graph (surfaceplot) from a Mat type of OpenCV using qwtplot3D?

Tags: c++, opencv, graph, 3d, qt4

I have a 2D Mat data/image using OpenCV. I would like to plot a 3D graph from it, the row as x-axis, column as y-axis & the pixel values on each coordinate(row,column) as z-axis. I would like to plot the graph similar to the surf function in Matlab. I tried to use the
bool loadFromData (double **data, unsigned int columns, unsigned int rows, double minx, double maxx, double miny, double maxy)
function but my program crashed when I debugged till this line. I am actually very new in using this qwtplot3d & qt4, so please help me see where i go wrong.

What I did is copying all the pixel values into an array, then try to make it into a 2D array made of rows and columns and pass it to loadFromData like below:

```
//abs_outcorr is Mat type of opencv
int rows= abs_outcorr.rows;
int columns= abs_outcorr.cols * abs_outcorr.channels();

double fromMat[columns*rows];

for (int j=0; j<rows; j++)
{
double* data= abs_outcorr.ptr<double>(j); //access the pixel value from Mat
for (int i=0; i<columns; i++)
{
fromMat[i] = data[i];
}
}

double** x = new double * [rows];
for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
x[i] = new double[rows];

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
for(int j=0; j<columns; j++)
x[j][i] = fromMat[columns*i + j];

for( int i=0; i<columns; i++)
delete x[i];
delete []x;

/* My main project is based on mainwindow with some buttons.
All these codes I implemented in a button clicked & I would like to pop out the graph,
but not sure the codes below work, please help me */

QWidget window;
window.setWindowTitle("plot 3d");
QHBoxLayout layout;
Qwt3D::SurfacePlot qsp(&window);

qsp.loadFromData(x, columns, rows, 0, columns, 0, rows);
qsp.setRotation(30,0,15);
qsp.setScale(1,1,1);
qsp.setShift(0.15,0,0);
qsp.setZoom(0.9);
for (unsigned i=0; i!=qsp.coordinates()->axes.size(); ++i)
{
qsp.coordinates()->axes[i].setMajors(7);
qsp.coordinates()->axes[i].setMinors(4);
}

qsp.coordinates()->axes[Qwt3D::X1].setLabelString("x");
qsp.coordinates()->axes[Qwt3D::Y1].setLabelString("y");
qsp.coordinates()->axes[Qwt3D::Z1].setLabelString("z");
qsp.setCoordinateStyle(Qwt3D::BOX);
qsp.updateData();
qsp.updateGL();

qsp.show();
layout.addWidget(&qsp);
window.setLayout(&layout);
window.resize(1000,800);
window.show();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//These are some of my pixel value of my Mat (32x32)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Row 0 Column 0 9.61749e-08
Row 0 Column 1 2.16608e-09
Row 0 Column 2 3.25873e-08
Row 0 Column 3 2.65754e-08
Row 0 Column 4 2.93116e-08
Row 0 Column 5 6.55923e-08
Row 0 Column 6 4.56592e-08
Row 0 Column 7 4.91113e-08
Row 0 Column 8 1.73816e-08
Row 0 Column 9 2.27045e-10
Row 0 Column 10 7.36088e-08
.
.
.
Row 16 Column 16 1
.
.
.
Row 31 Column 23 5.1846e-08
Row 31 Column 24 1.01708e-07
Row 31 Column 25 4.25331e-09
Row 31 Column 26 2.77903e-08
Row 31 Column 27 1.14044e-08
Row 31 Column 28 6.03817e-08
Row 31 Column 29 2.65248e-08
Row 31 Column 30 1.46648e-08
Row 31 Column 31 8.05808e-08
```

Basically this Mat/image is a bright dot in the centre with value of 1, while the rest all black which are nearly 0.
The expected result should look like a sharp straight peak in the middle of the plot.
Thanks.